# How to add dynamic image in jasper report using jasper studio

Tags: jasper-reports

How to add dynamic image in jasper report using jasper studio.Database is postgresql

image is stored in bytea format

how to display that image in jasper report.

How to solve this?? is there any other method?

data base query ->

select encode(image,'escape') as img,id from entity_image where entity_id = 100

image expression-> 
new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($F{image}.getBytes()))

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: data base query  ->                                                                                           
 select encode(image,'escape') as img,id
from entity_image where entity_id = 100                                                                             image expression->                                                                                                       new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64($F{image}.getBytes()))

Comment: Could you add this in question ?

Comment: You don't need to encode/decode the bytea data.  Just do select image as img ..., set the field type to java.awt.Image and use $F{image} as image expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to encode/decode the bytea data.

Just directly select the bytea column as in `select image, id ...`, set the field type to `java.awt.Image` and use `$F{image}` as image expression.